# VS Code não está pesquisando nas pastas de bibliotecas (Vendor, node_modules, etc) depois de atualizar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Depois que eu atualizei o meu VS Code, ao apertar o atalho CTRL+P, não consigo mais visualizar classes de biblioteca de terceiros instaladas na pasta `vendor`.

Notei que o mesmo comportamento ocorre para a pasta `node_modules`.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver isso, basta apertar o atalho <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (ou **File >> preferences >> settings**) e adicionar a seguinte linha à configuração:

```
 "search.useIgnoreFiles": false
```

Isso resolveu o problema.

É importante lembrar que nem sempre você deseja que as pesquisas sejam feitas em algumas pastas. Para ignorar pastas específicas, use a seguinte linha na configuração:

```
 "search.useIgnoreFiles": {
       "./node_modules" : true
 }
```

Lembre-se que, se quer usar essa configuração especificamente para apenas um projeto, faça essa edição em "Workspace Setting" ao invés de "User Settings".